# whitespace-cleanup stopped working

Tags: whitespace-mode

I'm not sure what I did, but I'm trying to use `M-x whitespace-cleanup` in a python file and nothing happens. How do I debug this?

Comment: Have you tried it with no init file (`emacs -Q`)?

Comment: I tried now and this seams to work. So best would be to comment everything and see what prevents it?

Comment: You can try to bisect your init file manually or use a tool like https://github.com/Malabarba/elisp-bug-hunter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I narrowed it down to the following line

```
(setq whitespace-style ' (face space-mark tab-mark))
```

If I remove it `whitespace-cleanup` works. Probably I'm overwriting something that is necessary for it to work. If I change the line to

```
(setq-default whitespace-style ' (face tabs spaces trailing space-before-tab newline indentation empty space-after-tab space-mark tab-mark newline-mark))
```

everything works fine.